# How can I catch asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError from dns.asyncresolver.Resolver?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm running a load of DNS lookups through dns.asyncresolver and around 0.05% of them are throwing:

```
Exception in callback _SelectorDatagramTransport._read_ready()
handle: <Handle _SelectorDatagramTransport._read_ready()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1021, in _read_ready
    self._protocol.datagram_received(data, addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dns/_asyncio_backend.py", line 30, in datagram_received
    self.recvfrom.set_result((data, addr))
asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: invalid state
```

If I edit /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dns/_asyncio_backend.py from:

```
    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        if self.recvfrom:
            self.recvfrom.set_result((data, addr))
            self.recvfrom = None
```

To:

```
    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        if self.recvfrom:
            try:
                self.recvfrom.set_result((data, addr))
            except Exception as e:
                print(self.recvfrom)
            self.recvfrom = None
```

I instead get:

```
# python3 asynctest.py
<Future cancelled>
<Future cancelled>
<Future cancelled>
```

Is there any way I can catch this without editing Python library files, which I'd really rather not do?

Test code below:

```
from dns.asyncresolver import Resolver
import asyncio
import sqlite3
 
async def getIPs():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('hosts.db')
    c    = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT DISTINCT job.host FROM job')
    # sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT job.host FROM job LIMIT 10;
    # .
    # 163mx00.mxmail.netease.com.
    # 163mx01.mxmail.netease.com.
    # 163mx02.mxmail.netease.com.
    # 163mx03.mxmail.netease.com.
    # a.dailymotion.com.
    # a.iana-servers.net.
    # a.icann-servers.net.
    # a.mx.openstreetmap.org.
    # a.ns.apple.com.
    # Total: 10,259
    lookups = c.fetchall()
    res = Resolver()
    sema = asyncio.Semaphore(500)
    output = [get_ips(domain[0], res, sema) for domain in lookups]
    await asyncio.gather(*output, return_exceptions=False)
 
async def get_ips(domain, res, sema):
    async with sema:
        try:
            ip = await res.resolve(domain, 'A')
            for result in ip:
                result = result.to_text()
                break
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        try:
            ip = await res.resolve(domain, 'AAAA')
            for result in ip:
                result = result.to_text()
                break
        except Exception as e:
            pass
 
asyncio.run(getIPs())
```